# React multi-language issue

Tags: reactjs

How can i making mistake. I am fetching language data through json file but language resource key not working properly.

```
import i18next from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'

import { formatDate } from './util'

export const setUiLocale = (locale) => {
    
    return fetch(`/assets/locales/${locale}/translation.json`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(loadedResources => (
                
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    i18next
                    .use(LanguageDetector)
                    .use(initReactI18next)
                    .init({
                        lng: locale,
                        debug: true,
                        resources: { [locale]:  loadedResources },
                        detection: {
                        order: ['path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag'],
                        caches: ['cookie'],
                        },
                        interpolation: {
                            format: function (value, format, locale) {
                                if (value instanceof Date) {
                                    return formatDate(value, format, locale)
                                }

                                return value
                            }
                        }
                    }, (err, t) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err)
                            return
                        }

                        resolve()
                    })
                })
            ))
            .catch(err => Promise.reject(err))
}
```

```
export const t = (key, opt) => i18next.t(key, opt)
```

Error:
i18next::translator: missingKey en translation welcome_message welcome_message

Comment: Can you check if you have "welcome_message" in your i18n?

Comment: I was missed translation object under json file. It's working now.
```
"translation": {
    "welcome_message": "Welcome"
  }
```